# Issues renaming images during upload

Tags: images

The main reason for adding this snippet is all about SEO. The people I sometimes make websites for often aren't that savvy with WP and tend to upload their stuff just as is. As these are often media related websites I try to help them a bit by automatically renaming their uploads from `DSC_0010.JPG` to `my-optimized-post-title-001.JPG`, etc.

---

I'm currently using [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/rename-files-during-upload-using-variables) snippet which renames my files during upload.

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_modify_uploaded_file_names', 1, 1 );
function my_modify_uploaded_file_names( $image_name ) {
  // get the parent post id, if there is one
  if ( isset( $_GET['post_id'] ) ) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
  } elseif ( isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) ) {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
  }
  // only do this if we got the post id, otherwise they're probably in the media section rather than uploading an image from a post
  if ( is_numeric( $post_id ) ) {
    // get the post slug
    $post_obj  = get_post( $post_id );
    $post_slug = $post_obj->post_name;
    // if we found a slug
    if ( $post_slug ) {
      $random_number = rand( 10000, 99999 );
      $image_name['name'] = $post_slug . '-' . $random_number . '.jpg';
    }
  }
  return $image_name;
}
```

However, when having `WP_DEBUG` set to true it giving me this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: post_id in /home/lorem/public_html/clients/ipsum/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/test.php on line 18
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lorem/public_html/clients/ipsum/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/test.php:504) in /home/lorem/public_html/clients/ipsum/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 864
```

From the question linked to people tell it's missing the `$_GET` variables. Something I'm unable to solve myself...

Does someone know perhaps on how to get this script working again? (or know perhaps a similar solution?)

Comment: I don't get it... this code works for me... also, you may want to put an extension checker so you don't rename every filetype to JPG

Comment: sorry, the original post does warns about the filetype checking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sent Header

The following error simply states that the error message was output directly (sent header)

> ```
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lorem/public_html/clients/ipsum/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/test.php:504) in /home/lorem/public_html/clients/ipsum/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 864
> ```

---

#### PHP Error notice

> ```
> Notice: Undefined variable: post_id in /home/lorem/public_html/clients/ipsum/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/test.php on line 18
> ```

`$_REQUEST` is a combination of a lot of things, and it also takes stuff from `$_POST` and `$_GET`. So the 1st thing I'd try is to drop your `if/else` statement and replace it with a simple `$_REQUEST['post_id']`.

#### Some other ideas

I understand, that the idea behind the snippet is that you also modify images that are just selected and not uploaded exclusively for that post. Else I can't understand why all this is necessary. Therefore I'd try the following:

```
function modify_uploaded_file_names( $image ) 
{
    // Use part of the post or user object to rename the image
    get_currentuserinfo();
    global $post, $current_user;

    $random_number = rand( 10000, 99999 );

    // only do this if we got the post id, 
    // otherwise they're probably in the media section 
    // rather than uploading an image from a post
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) )
    {
        // get the ID
        $post_id  = absint( $_REQUEST['post_id'] );

        // get the post OBJECT
        $post_obj  = get_post( $post_id );

        // get the post slug
        $post_slug = $post_obj->post_name;

        switch( $image['type'] )
        {
            case 'image/jpeg' :
                $suffix = 'jpg';
                break;

            case 'image/png' :
                $suffix = 'png';
                break;

            case 'image/gif' :
                $suffix = 'gif';
                break;
        }

        // if we found a slug
        if ( $post_slug ) 
            $image['name'] = "{$post_slug}-{$random_number}.{$suffix}";
    }
    else 
    {
        $image_name    = str_place( ' ', '-', strtolower( $current_user->data->user_nicename ) );
        $image['name'] = "{$image_name}-{$random_number}.jpg";
    }

    return $image;
}
// Only one arg, so 4th attr not needed - Priority set to later 20
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_modify_uploaded_file_names', 20 );
```

Comment: Thanks @kaiser!, I am however stuck on this line `$post_obj  = get_post( (int) $_REQUEST['post_id'] );`, which is causing me a `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference`

Comment: See update & give it a try. Fun is the `reference` - ain't got a clue why there should be a reference to the post ID.

Comment: @Charlie Could you please tell what your problem was, so later readers can profit from that?

Comment: Sure. The main problem were the errors and notifications mentioned of course. But the main reason for adding this snippet is all about SEO. The people I sometimes make websites for often aren't that savvy with WP and tend to upload their stuff just as is. As these are often media related websites I try to help them a bit by automatically renaming their uploads from `DSC_0010.JPG` to `my-optimized-post-title-001.JPG`, etc.

Comment: @Charlie See update: If no post title was found, the user nice name (lowercase with spaces replaced by dashes) jump in. Point is that this still brings up weired results if the auto save process already hooked in.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Interesting to see you've been using `user_nicename`. I've been messing around with `sanitize_title_with_dashes( $post_obj->post_title );` myself. I've also been messing with the image ext as well using `pathinfo`, though this only seems to work when using `sanitize_file_name` instead of `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` (probably I'll be switching to that instead). Edit: I'm still having some mixed feelings about `$random_number`, and perhaps go for a modified `wp_unique_filename` instead (I really do like the dash between the name and the number :))

Comment: Interesting idea. I didn't know about `wp_unique_filename()`. I guess I'll look into that next week. Thanks for the update :)

Comment: Thanks again. For what it's worth, this is what I'm currently having (mostly based on your previous answer): https://gist.github.com/2329856