# Rename image uploads with width in filename

Tags: php, images, filters, uploads

I am attempting to change the name format that WordPress uses to rename uploaded files. For example, when I upload an image with filename `cat-picture.jpg` WordPress will create scaled versions and rename the filename to variations of `cat-picture-{WIDTHxHEIGHT}.jpg`. Is there a way I am able to move this width & height attribute to the beginning of the filename so instead I get variations of `{WIDTHxHEIGHT}-cat-picture.jpg`? So, in the context of this example, I'd like the filename to be renamed to `600x400-cat-picture.jpg`. Thoughts?

I've looked at [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/issues-renaming-images-during-upload) and [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/rename-files-during-upload-using-variables), but I am unable to come up with a working solution. Here's my code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'modify_uploaded_file_names', 20);
function modify_uploaded_file_names( $image ) {
    // Get default name of uploaded file and set to variable
    $imagename = $image['name'];
    // Case switch for multiple file extensions
    switch ( $image['type'] ) {
        case 'image/jpeg' :
            $suffix = 'jpg';
            break;
        case 'image/png' :
            $suffix = 'png';
            break;
        case 'image/gif' :
            $suffix = 'gif';
            break;
    }
    // Get size of uploaded image and assign to variable
    $imagesize = getimagesize($image);
    // Re-structure uploaded image name
    $image['name'] = "{$imagesize[0]}x{$imagesize[1]}-{$imagename}.{$suffix}";

    return $image;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I can answer your question, but please make sure that you include what you're actually trying to do. it's possible that people can suggest a different solution to the initial problem you're trying to solve. (This is sometimes called the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to do it with the filter [**`image_make_intermediate_size`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_make_intermediate_size).

Probably all the `path/filename.extension` dismembering and remaking could be optimized or made in a single stroke fashion, but alas, I'll let that to the reader:

```
// The filter runs when resizing an image to make a thumbnail or intermediate size.
add_filter( 'image_make_intermediate_size', 'rename_intermediates_wpse_82193' );

function rename_intermediates_wpse_82193( $image ) 
{
    // Split the $image path into directory/extension/name
    $info = pathinfo($image);
    $dir = $info['dirname'] . '/';
    $ext = '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = wp_basename( $image, "$ext" );

    // Build our new image name
    $name_prefix = substr( $name, 0, strrpos( $name, '-' ) );
    $size_extension = substr( $name, strrpos( $name, '-' ) + 1 );
    $new_name = $dir . $size_extension . '-' . $name_prefix . $ext;

    // Rename the intermediate size
    $did_it = rename( $image, $new_name );

    // Renaming successful, return new name
    if( $did_it )
        return $new_name;

    return $image;
}
```

Comment: PS: I did only basic tests of uploading in a post and inserting intermediates in content, so far so good...

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!! So just to clarify, this function will run every time a file is uploaded, correct? Trying to fully understand, but this function will rename every intermediate file created on upload? Also, I'm curious if there would be a way to instead format the renamed file so that instead, only the width would be in the filename. ie like: "600-cat-picture.jpg" instead of "600x400-cat-picture.jpg". This format would work better with my responsive image script. Any thoughts/help you could share? Thank you.

Comment: @kaffolder, I've added comments to the code, so it's clear what each part is doing. Yes, it's possible to use only the width, you need to [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5159086/1287812) to the `$size_extension` string ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @brasofilo! Spot on!! This will help immensely with the responsive foresight.js image plugin I'm working on. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to know, @kaffolder! Ping us the link to the plugin here when it's finished ;)