# rename attachments based on parent-post-title on upload

Tags: attachments, uploads

I know there a some functions already avaible here for this task, but none of them seem to work as needed.

The best way seems to me adding a filter to **wp_handle_upload_prefilter** like [kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser) does in [this example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47329/28046). Unfortunately the file only gets the parent-post-title if the post is already saved to the database.

---

Another approach is to add a function to **add_attachment** like [Ijaas](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9085/ijaas) does [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30767/28046). Then the file gets the parent-post-title as name, but no thumbnails are created. And my attempt in using [wp_generate_attachment_metadata();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) to create the missing image sizes, ended in an endless loop (propably cause I'm using it the wrong way, but now I'm a bit scared by this function).

---

Would be great if there was a way to pass the title to **wp_handle_upload_prefilter** even if the post isn't saved yet.

Oh by the way, this is my endless function, maybe somebody can tell me what's wrong with it.
**DON'T USE THIS FUNCTION !!!**

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'fkp_rename_attacment');
function fkp_rename_attacment($post_ID){

  $post = get_post($post_ID);
  $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
  $path = pathinfo($file);
  $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
  $p_author = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $parent->post_author );
  $p_author_san = sanitize_title($p_author);

  $newfilename = $parent->post_name . '-' . $p_author_san . '-' . $post_ID;
  $newfile = $path['dirname']."/".$newfilename.".".$path['extension'];

  rename($file, $newfile);    

  $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($newfile), null );
  $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $attachment = array(
    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $newfile ), 
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($newfile)),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
   );
  $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $newfile, $parent->ID );
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $newfile );
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
}
```

**DON'T USE THIS FUNCTION !!!**

Comment: Would it fix the problem to replace  `wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );` with `remove_action('add_attachment', 'fkp_rename_attacment');
 wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
 add_action('add_attachment', 'fkp_rename_attacment');` ?

Comment: Maybe someone could tell me what causes the endless loop in my function. That would help me A LOT.

Comment: `add_attachment` gets called on `wp_insert_attachment`, which you call within your function.

Comment: Oh thank you! But I tried to remove it and add it again at the end, like posted in the comment above and get an endless loop too. However this already helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to add a function to `publish_post` and creating a lot of unnecessary files I tried to blemish [kaisers function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47329/28046) to fit my needs.

```
function modify_uploaded_file_names( $image ) {
    // Use part of the post or user object to rename the image
    get_currentuserinfo();
    global $post, $current_user;

    // only do this if we got the post id, 
    // otherwise they're probably in the media section 
    // rather than uploading an image from a post
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        // get the ID
        $post_id  = absint( $_REQUEST['post_id'] );

        // get the post OBJECT
        $post_obj  = get_post( $post_id );

        // get the post slug
        $post_slug = sanitize_title($post_obj->post_title); 

        // get the author
        $author = sanitize_title( get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post_obj->post_author ) );

        switch( $image['type'] ) {
            case 'image/jpeg' :
                $suffix = 'jpg';
                break;

            case 'image/png' :
                $suffix = 'png';
                break;

            case 'image/gif' :
                $suffix = 'gif';
                break;
        }

        // if we found a slug
        if ( $post_slug ) 
            $image['name'] = "{$author}-{$post_slug}-{$random_number}.{$suffix}";
    }
    else {
        $image_name    = str_place( ' ', '-', strtolower( $current_user->data->user_nicename ) );
        $image['name'] = $image_name . '-' . $file['name'];
    }

    return $image;
}

// Only one arg, so 4th attr not needed - Priority set to later 20
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_modify_uploaded_file_names', 20 );
```

There are only some small changes

1. replaced `$post_obj->post_name` with `sanitize_title($post_obj->post_title)` since post_name only was present in my tests when the post already was saved.
2. deleted the random-numbers, cause `wp_handle_upload` uses [wp_unique_filename()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_filename) anyway.
3. Added the author-name to the file-name, but that's just something I need.