# Images in upload folder with hexadecimal names

Tags: images, uploads

I'm using Wordpress 3.4.1 with the Suffusion theme 4.3.0.

I've noticed that there are a large number of images with hexadecimal names, like 54f96e1d5f478186f66bde9d6aeda625.jpeg. I'm wondering how these images are being created, and what I can do to prevent their generation, as they don't seem to be used by any post.

Comment: What do you see when you display one of those images ?

Comment: A regular image, which is likely a duplicate of another image.

Comment: Could be the theme or some plugin... Does a search for the string `54f96e1d5f478186f66bde9d6aeda625` in the database returns something?

Answer (score 0):

Testing the plugin provided in [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71629/12615), I just saw that `media_handle_sideload` generates exactly this pattern, `jpeg` extension as well (instead of `jpg`).

Following its path through the core, it seems that only the filter `wp_handle_upload` could be used for dealing with that.

But a brief research shows an interesting use of `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`: [Rename files during upload using variables](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5505/12615).

A way of finding which element is using `media_handle_sideload` is:
- drop all the plugins and theme folders/files into a good editor (NotePad++, TextMate, etc) and do a global search for this filter.

After finding where it's being called, a rename strategy can be thought of.

<sup>*All this assuming the Sideload is responsible in OP's case*</sup>